# regex number in href url in python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a number from an URL like this:
https://ghostbin.com/paste/dmjvt
I want to extract the number 3
I managed to extract from \li to /li with beatifulsoup, I can't seem to manage to do a regex to extract this single number from the \a href since some numbers may come behind it
What would be a regex in python to accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Well i don't see sufficient information provided in question. please add sufficient information

Comment: What's missing there? My working block is https://ghostbin.com/paste/2hdyd and I want to extract the number after /page/ and before /# , but the issue is, there might be numbers before /page/ . How can I extract it then with a python regex?

Comment: Please add the data that you've linked to into the question. Links may expire, rendering your question meaningless for future readers.

Comment: I tried to, but the question got really screwed up, besides I set the paste not to expire.

Comment: Well things are still not clear you have to regex just for extracting number or it should search for valid url also ?

Comment: Just for extracting that specific number after /page/ and before /#

Comment: @j.doe you can see this https://regex101.com/r/7lafAJ/1/

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/f428w It's still not working with that, I get either None or AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' @CodeManiac

Comment: @j.doe it's working in demo link just check which i have provided.

Comment: I saw the demo link, but I can't seem to get it to work on the actual program...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using this regex `/page/(\d+)/`

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<li class="page-item pagination-end">
  <a class="page-link page-text" href="xxx/page/3/#filters">3</a>
</li>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
endNav = soup.select_one('.page-item.pagination-end a')
navNumber = re.search(r'/page/(\d+)/', endNav['href']).group(1)
print(navNumber) # 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was about the implementation...!